# SVG not scaling with page resize React

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, autoresize

I have an animated SVG in react that is supposed to draw some lines down the screen starting from the top to the bottom relative to 100vh adn 100vw. the problem is it works on my native resolution but not when the window is resized (i made the svg in gimp in respect to my native res). I have tried every single css combination i can think of but i just cant get it to work as needed.

(images at the bottom for an idea of what it should look like vs what happens when resized)

thanks in advance :)

SVG:

```
<svg className="line_svg"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="auto" height="100%"
        viewBox="0 0 2560 1440">
        <path id="Selection"
          fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2"
          d="M 1279.00,0.00
           C 1280.66,5.65 1283.93,7.93 1288.00,12.00
             1288.00,12.00 1306.00,30.00 1306.00,30.00
             1306.00,30.00 1374.00,98.00 1374.00,98.00
             1374.00,98.00 1548.00,271.00 1548.00,271.00
             1548.00,271.00 1606.00,329.00 1606.00,329.00
             1612.96,335.96 1631.41,355.28 1638.00,360.00
             1638.00,360.00 1610.91,389.00 1610.91,389.00
             1610.91,389.00 1576.91,425.00 1576.91,425.00
             1576.91,425.00 1549.09,454.00 1549.09,454.00
             1549.09,454.00 1457.91,551.00 1457.91,551.00
             1457.91,551.00 1396.09,616.00 1396.09,616.00
             1396.09,616.00 1151.91,875.00 1151.91,875.00
             1151.91,875.00 1124.09,904.00 1124.09,904.00
             1124.09,904.00 1014.91,1020.00 1014.91,1020.00
             1014.91,1020.00 989.04,1047.00 989.04,1047.00
             989.04,1047.00 978.00,1059.00 978.00,1059.00
             978.00,1059.00 965.83,1072.00 965.83,1072.00
             964.29,1073.71 960.88,1076.96 960.17,1079.00
             959.20,1081.77 961.03,1083.93 962.63,1086.00
             962.63,1086.00 976.00,1101.00 976.00,1101.00
             976.00,1101.00 1030.58,1162.00 1030.58,1162.00
             1030.58,1162.00 1087.83,1226.00 1087.83,1226.00
             1087.83,1226.00 1213.83,1367.00 1213.83,1367.00
             1213.83,1367.00 1261.07,1420.00 1261.07,1420.00
             1266.18,1425.63 1275.10,1437.95 1282.00,1440.00
             1280.25,1433.86 1276.28,1430.56 1272.08,1426.00
             1272.08,1426.00 1256.07,1408.00 1256.07,1408.00
             1256.07,1408.00 1196.16,1341.00 1196.16,1341.00
             1196.16,1341.00 1044.16,1171.00 1044.16,1171.00
             1044.16,1171.00 993.17,1114.00 993.17,1114.00
             993.17,1114.00 963.00,1081.00 963.00,1081.00
             963.00,1081.00 975.04,1068.00 975.04,1068.00
             975.04,1068.00 1024.09,1016.00 1024.09,1016.00
             1024.09,1016.00 1052.91,986.00 1052.91,986.00
             1052.91,986.00 1144.09,889.00 1144.09,889.00
             1144.09,889.00 1205.91,824.00 1205.91,824.00
             1205.91,824.00 1450.09,565.00 1450.09,565.00
             1450.09,565.00 1477.91,536.00 1477.91,536.00
             1477.91,536.00 1586.09,421.00 1586.09,421.00
             1586.09,421.00 1612.96,393.00 1612.96,393.00
             1612.96,393.00 1623.00,382.00 1623.00,382.00
             1623.00,382.00 1635.28,369.00 1635.28,369.00
             1636.74,367.34 1640.17,363.91 1640.83,362.00
             1641.84,359.07 1639.76,357.00 1637.94,355.00
             1637.94,355.00 1623.00,340.00 1623.00,340.00
             1623.00,340.00 1560.00,277.00 1560.00,277.00
             1560.00,277.00 1359.00,77.00 1359.00,77.00
             1359.00,77.00 1304.00,22.00 1304.00,22.00
             1298.18,16.18 1286.24,2.12 1279.00,0.00 Z" />
      </svg>
```

CSS:

```
.front_page_parent{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.line_svg{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  stroke-dasharray: 6000;
  animation: draw 2s ease-in;
  fill: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Structure of App

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
        <FrontPage />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export const FrontPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="font_page_parent" style={BackgroundImageStyle}>
      <svg className="line_svg"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="auto" height="100%"
        viewBox="0 0 2560 1440">
        <path id="Selection"
          fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2"
          d="......."- />
      </svg>
     </div>
```

[working full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X8QR.jpg)

[not working resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki9Fg.png)

Comment: please try removing the width and the height of the svg element

Comment: i removed them and it works full screen still and on resize instead of being centered on the page like in the image i put up. It is at the top but does not go the whole way down